# How to delete a column in BigQuery that is part of a nested column

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, nested-lists

I want to delete a column in a BigQuery table that is part of a record or nested column. I've found this command in their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_drop_column_statement). Unfortunately, this command is not available for nested columns inside existing RECORD fields.
Is there any workaround for this?

For example, if I had this schema I want to remove the address2 field inside the address field. So from this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "addresses",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "REPEATED",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "address1",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "address2",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "country",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

to this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "addresses",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "REPEATED",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "address1",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "country",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You are right - column_name in those command(s) is the name of the top level column you're altering. Modifying subfields is not supported. Present your sample data with expected result and we will show you how [easily] this can be done :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below

```
select * replace(
  array(select as struct * except(address2) from t.addresses) 
  as addresses)
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

if you want permanently remove that field - use `create or replace table` as in below example

```
create or replace table `project.dataset.new_table` as 
select * replace(
  array(select as struct * except(address2) from t.addresses) 
  as addresses)
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

Comment: I *really* wish they'd allow you to `select * except(addresses.address2) from table`...