# How to delete a column inside a nested column in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried doing this query:

```
create or replace table `project.dataset.new_table` as 
    select * replace(
      array(select as struct * except(address2) from t.addresses) 
      as addresses)
    from `project.dataset.table` t
```

based on this question:
[How to delete a column in BigQuery that is part of a nested column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68412704/how-to-delete-a-column-in-bigquery-that-is-part-of-a-nested-column)

But I get this error:
"Values referenced in FROM clause must be arrays. t.addresses has type STRUCT<... "

The schema of my nested column is table is:

```
[
 {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "IsHappy",
        "type": "BOOLEAN"
      },
      {
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "Description",
            "type": "STRING"
          }
        ],
        "mode": "REPEATED",
        "name": "FuncTypes",
        "type": "RECORD"
      },

      {
        "name": "address2",   --->hoping to delete this
        "type": "INTEGER"
      },
  
    ],
    "name": "addresses",
    "type": "RECORD"
  }
]
```

May I ask what I should change or what the error means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below

```
create or replace table your_new_table as 
select * replace(
      (select as struct addresses.* except(address2)) 
      as addresses
  )
from your_table;
```

Comment: I tried to use "mynewtemptable" for "temp table" above but I get the error "mynewtemptable is not a supported object type at..."

Comment: not sure what you mean - anyway, try again ...

Comment: It's a great answer for simple use cases but I can't make it work to replace a nested struct. Imagine if addresses was an element inside a customer struct and so I wanted to achieve the following

```create or replace table your_new_table as

select * replace(
      (select as struct customer.addresses.* except(address2)) 
       as customer.addresses
 ) from your_table;```