# How to change the datatype of a field in a struct column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a struct column in BigQuery called `meta`. Inside that field, I have a field called `join_at` which is currently in a FLOAT datatype and I'd like to change it to a TIMESTAMP datatype.

I tried running this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `my-table` 
ALTER COLUMN meta.join_at SET DATA TYPE TIMESTAMP
```

That doesn't work. It throws an error at the "." character. So, apparently I can't just change the struct field like that.

What would be the correct approach in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you were wanting to alter a field in a struct you would do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE so_test.alter_struct(s1 STRUCT<a FLOAT64, b STRING>);

ALTER TABLE so_test.alter_struct ALTER COLUMN s1
SET DATA TYPE STRUCT<a TIMESTAMP, b STRING>;
```

However a FLOAT is not coercible to a TIMESTAMP as listed in this table here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules#comparison_chart

Instead you can take an approach similar to this:
[How to delete a column in BigQuery that is part of a nested column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68412704/how-to-delete-a-column-in-bigquery-that-is-part-of-a-nested-column)

And just define the new structure while overwriting the table.